# Scenario output gives wrong answer upon second loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, output

I'm pretty much done with this program except for this small problem.

The problem is when the first time I loop through the program with the following in put of `20.0 36.0 72.0 2.0 10.0 18.0 10.0` my output comes out to be `232.59 sec` which is correct.

For the second time I loop around, I input `25.0 72.0 200.0 1.5 8.0 30.0 20.0` my output comes out to be `800.41` which is wrong when it should be `1141.63`

Now if I reverse the inputs and take what I entered for the second loop for the first loop and first for the second loop. I do get my output of `1141.63` for the first loop, but the second loop, my answer is `1141.63` . I am very puzzled as to how this happening. One of my early solutions was to reset all variables back to 0 after each loop using another function, but that didn't seem to work and now I'm here.

EDIT: Problem figured out. Had to reset time and volFilled to 0 at the end of each loop.

```
void Well::timeReq()
{
    bool exit = false;

    while (!exit)
    {

        std::cout << "Enter 7 digits to evaluate or type 0 now to exit." << std::endl;

        std::cin >> UP;

        if (UP == 0)
        {
            exit = true;
            break;
        }

        std::cin >> D >> L >> B >> P >> DOWN >> V;

        double WL = L;

        double radius = (D / 2);

        while (volFilled < V)
        {

            time += UP;


            time += sqrt(2 * (L) / (acceleration * 12.0));


            time += (L) / (P);


            L += (B * cuIns) / (pi*pow(radius, 2));


            time += DOWN;
            volFilled += B;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Scenario " << scenario << ":" << std::endl;

        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(25) << "\tUp Hill"            << std::left << std::setw(30) << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
                  << UP << " sec" << std::endl;

        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(25) << "\tWell Diamter"       << std::left << std::setw(30) << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
                  << D << " in" << std::endl;

        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(25) << "\tWater Level"        << std::left << std::setw(30) << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
                  << WL << " in" << std::endl;

        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(25) << "\tBucket Volume"      << std::left << std::setw(30) << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
                  << B << " cu ft" << std::endl;

        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(25) << "\tBucket Ascent Rate" << std::left << std::setw(30) << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
                  << P << " in/sec" << std::endl;

        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(25) << "\tDownhill"           << std::left << std::setw(30) << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
                  << DOWN << " sec" << std::endl;

        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(25) << "\tRequired Volume"    << std::left << std::setw(30) << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
                  << V << " cu ft" << std::endl;

        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(25) << "\tTIME REQUIRED"      << std::left << std::setw(30) << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
                  << time << " sec" << std::endl;

        scenario++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your function reset all member variables back to their initial values? I just tested this out, resetting all variables after each iteration through the loop, and got your expected results.

Comment: You need to learn to use your debugger, step through the code and see what it is doing.

Comment: @Kevin I will try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may not completely fix your issue, you need to at least reinitialize your volFilled value back to 0.0 between scenarios. Otherwise you're just continuing from the previous scenario's volFilled, and that explains why the second test that you did with switching the scenarios yielded the same output. After the first scenario where volFilled reaches 20.0, it won't execute the logic inside the considion `while (volFilled < V)` in the second scenario because at this point, volFilled = 20 while V = 10.

Comment: OH! Jesus I'm blind. That made the second output more well rounded. In fact, I'm over the expected time just by a few dozen seconds but it's better than before. Thank you! :)